# Python Gstreamer: Take image array and put into Gstreamer

Tags: python, udp, gstreamer

I have similar problem like I have seen others have but I don't understand the solutions
I have a USB camera using its own capturing library and the resulting image-frame is stored in a share-memory, lets call it image.
So, I have an image object that I would like to further process with gstreamer.
So how can I do that. My knowledge ends at cv2.VideoCapture(gstr) (Which I do not use in this case since I have the image already. What I need to do is take an image I already have in the application and put into Gstreamer buffer somehow.
What I understand you can create an Appsrc name=source... and then I can take the image into a buffer.

All in all I jstu want to go from an Image array and be able to send it to a Gstream UDP sink and a multifilesink.

I hope it makes sense. I start with Basler USB3 camera and use their api to capture images, hence the confusion.

Comment: What about this (I have not tried it, just random search)? https://github.com/madams1337/python-opencv-gstreamer-examples/blob/master/gst_shm_to_app.py

Comment: Thanks. But I think that one is taking some sort of file-src and process.
I want to go directly from an image variable like an numpy-array and put into G-stream.
I found one way http://lifestyletransfer.com/how-to-use-gstreamer-appsrc-in-python/
but I dont know if that is optimal. I have also found joshdoe and his plugin. I got it working in console calling gst-launch-1.0, but not when moving into Python. Then I get Errors. Two approaches. Currently it seems the first is a working one, though I have more work on understanding how that particular system likes its pipelines.

Comment: you can still post your own answer, and someone may comment on the performance/optimisation possibilities